# Compare distances between real data and simulated data

Tags: r, statistical-significance, variance, bioinformatics

I have some data that shows the distance from a position in a genome `pos` to the nearest location (`min_dist`) of a genomic feature -- essentially the start sites for all genes in the genome: a transcription start site (TSS). It actually doesn't matter that this is a defined genomic feature, it could be anything.

Here is a visual representation of what I'm referring to:

[image]

I calculate the distance from each `pos` to the closest TSS and I call this `min_dist`. As each feature can be to the left or right of the closest TSS this value can be positive or negative.

I then represent this in a dataframe where each row represents a location in the genome `pos`, and the closest distance (+/-) `min_dist` to a TSS

I want to ask:

**Are these positions (`pos`) closer or further away from TSS than we would expect if they were randomly distributed?**

In order to ask this question, I have generated random positions in the genome for each row with which to compare my `pos` to. E.g.:

[image]

I am performing this simulation multiple times to get an overview of how frequently the simulated data differs from my real data.

I am currently doing a `wilcox` test to determine whether these simulated data are different from my experimental data. However, as I am comparing the means, this seems to be a poor choice of test as my simulated data may show a large variance but a similar mean to the real data.

The following R code produces data that illustrates the situation I have.

The code does the following:

1. Generate random data between `-1000:1000` as stand-in for the real data and `-5000:5000` for the simulated data -- which is a fairly extreme difference.
2. I then perform a `wilcox` test comparing `min_dist` between `sources` (`Real` & `Sim`) per iteration (simulated).
3. I then plot the data faceted by iteration. Each plot shows the density of positions per-iteration coloured by `Source` with the pseudo-real data in red and the simulated data in blue.

As can be seen, the `wilcox` test returns no statistically significant comparisons, even though the real data show a different spread very clearly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

set.seed(42)

dummyReal <- data.frame(Source=rep('Real'), min_dist=sample(-1000:1000, 1000), iteration=rep(1:10))
dummySim <- data.frame(Source=rep('Sim'), min_dist=sample(-5000:5000, 1000), iteration=rep(1:10))
dummyCombined <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::full_join(dummyReal, dummySim))

dummyCoc <- dummyCombined %>%
      group_by(iteration) %>%
      do(tidy(wilcox.test(min_dist ~ Source, exact=FALSE, data = . ))) %>%
      arrange(p.value) %>%
      ungroup()

print(dummyCoc, 10)
```

---

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   iteration statistic   p.value                                            method alternative
       <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>                                            <fctr>      <fctr>
 1         1    4379.0 0.1294880 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
 2         6    4445.0 0.1754624 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
 3         2    4663.0 0.4109625 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
 4         4    5328.5 0.4228817 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
 5         8    5323.0 0.4307008 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
 6        10    4865.0 0.7424310 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
 7         5    5120.5 0.7693641 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
 8         9    4898.0 0.8041313 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
 9         3    4960.0 0.9231125 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
10         7    5037.5 0.9279650 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided
```

---

```
p <- ggplot(dummyCombined)
p <- p + geom_density(aes(min_dist, fill = Source, group = Source), alpha = 0.4)
p <- p +facet_wrap(~iteration, nrow=5)
p
```

---

[image]

What tests would be more appropriate? Levene's test?

Comment: @downvoter - please explain how I can improve this question!

Comment: I stumbled across your question doing some research on my own. It's a very detailed question, which is good, but only the start! I find that on Stack it's best to start with a "TL;DR" at the top; basically create a really solid summary for the reader. Next, give full details in a bullet-style list, perhaps broken out into sections. The easier it is for the answer-er to digest your question, the more likely you'll get a great answer! Remember, [people only read for a little over 10 seconds!](https://litmus.com/blog/email-attention-spans-increasing-infographic) Stick with it, you'll do great :)

Answer (score 1):

There's alot going on in your question, so I'll focus my answer a little.

> *"I am currently doing a [`wilcox`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) test to determine whether these simulated data are different from my experimental data."*

[R's documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/wilcox.test) will tell you:

> ... if both `x` and `y` are given and `paired` is `FALSE`, a [Wilcoxon rank sum test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) [...] is carried out. In this case, the null hypothesis is that the distributions of `x` and `y` differ by a location shift of `mu` and the alternative is that they differ by some other location shift...

Since, you are after a difference in dispersion, it is not appropriate. Your p-values and plots are telling you that as well.

> *"What tests would be more appropriate? [Levene's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test)?"*

Yes, clearly this would be more appropriate, as it tests the equality of the variances of the two distributions. See e.g. [`lawstat::levene.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lawstat/versions/3.2/topics/levene.test), which includes the robust mean versions.

The most *general* test for detecting *a* difference between two distributions has to be the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). See e.g. [`stats::ks.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dgof/versions/1.2/topics/ks.test).